# Set textview XML in java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My app has edittext and a button. Everytime I click a button a new textview is added to activity. Below is the code:

```
public void novVnos (View v){
    EditText eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    RelativeLayout mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(eText.getText().toString()));
}

private TextView createNewTextView (String text){
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    int counter = 0;

    counter += 1;
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText(counter + ". " + text);
    return textView;
}
```

Now the thing is that whenever I add a new textview using the button, it is automatically placed in the upper left corner of the activity, but I want it somewhere else. I have already (manually) added a new textview to this activity and I want every new textview to be automatically placed UNDER this textview that already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really need to have a RelativeLayout there, I strongly suggest using a LinearLayout instead and setting the orientation to `vertical`, which would make all views be added below each other.

If you really need to have a RelativeLayout, there is of course a way also. But you will have to specify the correct LayoutParams. Each of the default viewgroups have it's own LayoutParams class.
Using [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) - especially the method `addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idOfOtherView)` - you can tell a view to be below another view.

Comment: yeah, that is what I call it thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a LinearLayout with vertical orientation on your XML and no a RelativeLayout.